# PDF Viewer in IPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am creating one app in which I need to view pdf, word, and excel files. Can I view these files without using web view? Can anyone provide me with sample code for doing the same.

Answer (score 1):

Or use a web based viewer like FlexPaper

http://flexpaper.devaldi.com

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use Quartz directly.  Documented here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH214-TPXREF101

Comment: Thanks for replying Lou..i have checked this link..but i m not getting where i should write this code..can u please help me by providing more detail...Actually i m very much new to this field..

Comment: They claim that there's full code at /Developer/Examples/Quartz/PDF/PDFViewer if you installed examples.  If not get them from the Xcode install.  It's for OSX, but the code should be similar

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CGPDFDocument (Apple doc [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFDocument/Reference/reference.html)).
This [blog](http://www.random-ideas.net/posts/42) also has very detailed explanation on how to implement it.